# active directory remote access

Tags: c#, active-directory

i have set up an active directory on an aws EC2 machine windows 2012 . 
it works great locally  .  I have installed Active directory explorer and locally i'm able to view the users etc...

the problem is that I'm trying to connect using ldap (using c#) from a computer which is outside the network . 
I'm able to log in succesfully since my EC2 has a public ip . 
so ValidateCredentials c# functions passes OK .

The problem is that when I try to query from a specific path to get the users I get an exception :
I call function :
DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://OU=Students,DC=hadoop,DC=com")
and no matter what path I try it is not working .
the exception i get is :
"the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted" .

I think that the problem is that the local hadoop.com is not accicible from outside the network since it does not have a public ip - it was a forest name locally created by me .

How can I overcome this problem so I can connect to my active directory server from a pc which is outside the network?

Many thanks

Comment: You can only connect to the folder is you can ping the server and the drive is shared.  If the PC is not on a public network (behind a firewall) To get through the firewall with some sort of port forwarding.

Comment: I shut down the firewall . and it still doesn't work? any idea how to procedd?

Comment: It has to be a public IP address so the IP gets advertise over the network.  The remote machine needs a route to the IP.   With port forwarding the remote machine could send to the firewall and then the firewall would recognize the port number and forward to the private network.

Comment: my ec2 machine does have a public address  . but my domain inside does not have a public ip . the firewall is down so it has no implications . can you please explian me what should I do since I'm a bit confused?

Comment: I think have a private network inside the your firewall.  Public addresses mean the outside world (Internet) can directly connected to a machine.  To be able to connect a route must exist between the local and remote machine.  The IP address must be unique so no other machine on the internet has same IP.  So then PING will work between the remote and local machine.  If it is a public IP then the firewall is not properly forwarding the messages.  So you would either have a Mask Issue on the firewall or a DNS issue.

Comment: Are you saying you have a laptop that works outside the company?  It works on a WIFI network?  That doesn't means it has a public IP.  The WIFI server assigns a temporary IP to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

So you're doing this:

```
DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://OU=Students,DC=hadoop,DC=com")
```

And it doesn't work. You have two issues.

1. When you provide an LDAP path with just a distinguished name like this, the Windows sends the request to the domain that the computer is joined to. If the object is on the same domain, all is good. If it's on a trusted domain, the DC returns a referral ("I can't tell you what that is, but I know who can") and your computer initiates a new request to the other DC. Since the computer you're running this from is not joined to that domain or a trusted domain then it has no idea where to go to find that object and so an exception is thrown. So you have to tell it where to go. You do that by including the domain name (or a specific DC name if you want) in the path:

```
LDAP://hadoop.com/OU=Students,DC=hadoop,DC=com
```

2. But you also need to pass credentials, which [`DirectoryEntry.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.exists?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't support. However, the [source code is available](https://source.dot.net/#System.DirectoryServices/System/DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry.cs,737) so you can just Steal and Modify™ to make a version that accepts credentials:

```cs
public static bool Exists(string path, string username, string password)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password);
    try
    {
        _ = entry.NativeObject;       // throws exceptions (possibly can break applications)
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80072030) ||
             e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80070003) ||   // ERROR_DS_NO_SUCH_OBJECT and path not found (not found in strict sense)
             e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800708AC))     // Group name could not be found
            return false;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        entry.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The one change you must make is changing the use of `Bind`, since that's an `internal` method and can't be used by mere mortals like us. Instead, I just get the [`NativeObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.nativeobject?view=netframework-4.8) property, which [calls `Bind()` for us](https://source.dot.net/#System.DirectoryServices/System/DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry.cs,279).

You can use that like this:

```cs
var ouExists = Exists("LDAP://hadoop.com/OU=Students,DC=hadoop,DC=com", "username", "password");
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure your security group has enabled the access for the LDAP and active directory ports

https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/cloud_volumes/aws/reference_security_groups_windows_ad_servers.html

Comment: thanks  , id did this but it still doesn't work - same exception .....

Comment: also notice that the ValidateCredentials  function is working this means that I pass the firewalls and the credentionals are ok . there is a problem with accesing the path which is a domain inside the windows server named hadoop.com I created ...